# mysql request across 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have one database with two tables:

**table1:** "backup1"

**table2:** "backup2"

both tables has a structure like

```
id, backupid, userid, backup, info
```

I would like to do a simple MYSQL request to get a group of entries where
it shows me what `userid` is found in `table1` and ALSO in `table2` *to see what users did backups in both tables*

I know I could open table1 look for a `userid` and do a another MYSQL to see if its also
in `table2`, but I hope there is a simpler way to do that with a single request.

Comment: `SELECT b1.userid FROM backup1 b1 JOIN backup2 b2 ON b1.userid = b2.userid`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT userid
FROM backup1
INNER JOIN backup2
USING(userid)
```

The inner join on the `userid` field will cause the query to only return rows that are found in both tables.

Comment: While this works, not explicitly defining the columns to match (ON a.userid=b.userid) scares me, similar to using the dreaded NATURAL JOIN.  Could just be my own OCD nature as a DBA but i always err on the side of being explicit when using joins. +1 though because this approach works.

Comment: You will need to specify which table to pull email from. like backup1.email

Comment: thanks ---
SELECT r1.userid, r1.email
FROM backup1 as r1
INNER JOIN backup2 as r2
USING(uidid) --- did the job.
first it didnt worked also ... only when i said AS (just backup1 r1) did nothing

Answer (score 1):

This isn't through '2 databases', this is through '2 tables'.  Just use a join.

```
SELECT a.userid
from backup1 a
inner join backup2 b
on a.userid=b.userid
```

This will give you all userids in backup1 that also exist in backup2

Comment: yours looks very simalar to "Bad Wolfs: Solution, but when I tried urs, very strange i did not got any result from my phpmyadmin.
not even a error. just kind a refresh of the pma page where i entered the SQL Command.

Answer (score 0):

if you only need to know if a user made a backup in both tables, you could simply use simple `select` statements. A simple example, using a temporary variable `@uId` to hold the Id of the user you want to check, and two temporary variables to hold the (boolean) answer for each table

```
set @uId = 1; -- The user Id
select
    @b_t1 := (select count(*) from table1 where userId=@uId) > 0 as hasBackupOnTable1,
    @b_t2 := (select count(*) from table2 where userId=@uId) > 0 as hasBackupOnTable2,
    @b_t1 and @b_t2 as hasBackupOnBothTables;
```

Comment: You're making this _way_ more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Never said it would be the easiest way, merely that it would work